# magento top search by sku

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

[image: Screenshot]

I am not getting 'sku' attribute wise top search in magento how to fix this issue, when am search box enter sku id but getting this issue Search Results For '901T-113'

Your search returns no results.

Answer (score 0):

Either problem is in the attribute's settings or indexing.

1. Navigate to `admin->catalog->attributes->Manage attributes` chose
   `SKU` attribute, there is a option named as `Use in Quick Search`
   set its value to be `Yes`.

[image]

2. Do `Reindexing` and clear your `cache`.

Comment: is there any anoter way to fix to this issue ?

Comment: are you using default magento search or any extension?

Comment: am using ajax search extension

Comment: can you provide me link of that extension? it is the extension which is causing this issue?

Comment: this is the extension link http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-search-and-autocomplete-extension-for-magento.html

Comment: are products showing when you you enter their SKU in search?

Comment: yes , am entered sku then show the results ajax search list but not getting the www.demosite.com/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=skuid like this

Comment: check is `ResultController.php` controller override in extension. This controller originally found `\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\controllers`

Comment: am tryed but no reslut

Comment: am getting like this Search Results For '273B710'
Your search returns no results.

Comment: try to print `$query->getQueryText()` in `indexAction` with placing `die;`

Comment: print  search key only on browser

Comment: Bad !! That's why there is nothing in search result.

Comment: I suggest you to use any other extension.

Comment: can you provide me your web address?